# Some videos on youtube drop to black screen

Tags: macos, mac, osx-el-capitan

Black screen issue playing video in youtube on Mac os x El Capitan 10.11.5, firefox

Comment: Not much detail to go on here.  Examples?  All?  Some?  Every time or random?  From the start or at random time in?  Entire screen or just browser tab or just the video?  Only on Firefox, OK on other browsers?  Always done it or new development?  What FF add-ons?  Have you tried running with add-ons disabled?

Comment: You should explain the issue in detail so that we can know what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Start Firefox in [Troubleshoot Firefox issues using Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode)  to check if one of the add-ons is causing the problem (switch to the DEFAULT theme: Tools > Add-ons > Themes).

- Please don't make any changes on the Safe mode.

See:

- [Troubleshoot extensions, themes and hardware acceleration issues to solve common Firefox problems](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-extensions-themes-to-fix-problems)
- [Troubleshoot issues with plugins like Flash or Java to fix common Firefox problems](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-issues-with-plugins-fix-problems)

If it does work in Safe-mode then disable all extensions and then try to find which is causing it by enabling one at a time until the problem reappears.

Use "Disable all add-ons" on the Troubleshoot Firefox issues using Safe Mode start window to disable all extensions.
Close and restart Firefox after each change via "Firefox > Quit".

If your problem doesn't solve then test this solution too:

- All cookies should be deleted from YouTube cookies by opening the Firefox Tools, going to options, going to Privacy, selecting Custom Settings from the drop down box, and deleting YouTube cookies.
- Firefox hardware acceleration should be disabled by going to Options> Advanced>selecting the 'Use hardware acceleration when available' checkbox> Restarting the browser.